# I want to append a dataframe to another one, even though they do not have the same size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question regarding the merging of two dataframes.
I have one dataframe, that looks like this

```
>> print(df)
     no  value1  value2
0    a     0    -1
1    b    -1     1
2    c    -1     1
3    d     0    -1
4    e    -1    -1
```

Now i have an additional dataframe, that looks like this

```
>> print(df2)
     no  value3  value4
0    a     1    -1
1    b     1    -1
2    e     1    -1
```

I would like to append the columns "value3" and "value4" of the second dataframe to the first one BUT only where they have matching values for the "no" column.
So in the end I would like to have a final dataframe, that looks like this:

```
>> print(df)
     no  value1  value2  value3  value4
0    a     0      -1      1       -1
1    b    -1       1      1       -1
2    c    -1       1     NaN      NaN
3    d     0      -1     NaN      NaN
4    e    -1      -1      1       -1
```

Is there an easy solution to do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `concat` and pass `axis=1` and `ignore_index=True`:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use merge

```
pd.merge(df, df2, on=['no'], how='outer')

  no  value1  value2  value3  value4
0  a       0      -1     1.0    -1.0
1  b      -1       1     1.0    -1.0
2  c      -1       1     NaN     NaN
3  d       0      -1     NaN     NaN
4  e      -1      -1     1.0    -1.0
```

Comment: then i loose the additional information in df (rows c and d), since they are not in df2

Comment: @nieka add how = 'outer', [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 6):

Use `pd.concat` with `set_index` to let Pandas use intrinsic data alignment.

```
pd.concat([df.set_index('no'),df2.set_index('no')], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  index  value1  value2  value3  value4
0     a       0      -1     1.0    -1.0
1     b      -1       1     1.0    -1.0
2     c      -1       1     NaN     NaN
3     d       0      -1     NaN     NaN
4     e      -1      -1     1.0    -1.0
```

Comment: this solution works as well, just for my understanding: is there an advantage of this method over the one from @Steven G?

Comment: @nieka see `axis=1`

Answer (score 2):

You are treating the column `'no'` like an index.  If so, you should consider placing it in the index.

**`pd.DataFrame.merge`**
@StevenG's answer is most idiomatic and extremely simple.  The problem is that `pd.DataFrame.merge` doesn't care about the index.  It will generate a new dataframe with values as they should be, but the index bears no resemblance to what was there.

```
df.set_index(df.index + 100)

    no  value1  value2
100  a       0      -1
101  b      -1       1
102  c      -1       1
103  d       0      -1
104  e      -1      -1
```

I'd want to see those same index values when I do

```
pd.merge(df.set_index(df.index + 100), df2, on=['no'], how='left')

  no  value1  value2  value3  value4
0  a       0      -1     1.0    -1.0
1  b      -1       1     1.0    -1.0
2  c      -1       1     NaN     NaN
3  d       0      -1     NaN     NaN
4  e      -1      -1     1.0    -1.0
```

But I don't

---

**pd.concat**
@ScottBoston's also destroys the index.  The advantage lies in that it treats the `'no'` column like an index.  If it is unique, then it may improve performance over larger dataframes (untested).

---

## Solution

**`pd.DataFrame.join`**
I propose the use of `join` because it is designed to work on indices.  And even though we aren't joining on an index, we do preserve the index that is there.

```
df.join(df2.set_index('no'), on='no')

  no  value1  value2  value3  value4
0  a       0      -1     1.0    -1.0
1  b      -1       1     1.0    -1.0
2  c      -1       1     NaN     NaN
3  d       0      -1     NaN     NaN
4  e      -1      -1     1.0    -1.0
```

Test that we do protect the index

```
df.set_index(df.index + 100).join(df2.set_index('no'), on='no')

    no  value1  value2  value3  value4
100  a       0      -1     1.0    -1.0
101  b      -1       1     1.0    -1.0
102  c      -1       1     NaN     NaN
103  d       0      -1     NaN     NaN
104  e      -1      -1     1.0    -1.0
```

We do!

Answer (score 1):

Just for Fun `map`

```
df2=df2.set_index('no')
for c in df2.columns:
    df1[c] = df1['no'].map(df2[c]).values


Out[828]: 
  no  value1  value2  value3  value4
0  a       0      -1     1.0    -1.0
1  b      -1       1     1.0    -1.0
2  c      -1       1     NaN     NaN
3  d       0      -1     NaN     NaN
4  e      -1      -1     1.0    -1.0
```